# In the wordpress Divi theme when I test the website In the waterfall section I have issues with fonts how can I fix these problems?

Tags: wordpress, performance, divi

In the wordpress Divi theme when I test the website In the waterfall section I have issues with fonts how can I fix these problems?

[image]

Comment: Melika Davoodi, Are You Using Default Divi Fonts ?

Comment: I'm using custom font. I added custom font from appearance > fonts